# How do I URL-escape a string in Mathematica?

Tags: url, escaping, wolfram-mathematica

For example,

```
urlesc["foo.cgi?abc=123"]
```

should return

```
foo.cgi%3Fabc%3D123
```

This is also known as [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Also, for better readability, spaces should encode to pluses.
I believe that's always acceptable for URL escaping.

Comment: Favorited. This is something I want to do once every six months or so, and I always end up re-rolling something to sort of get the job done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another method, using J/Link and [`java.net.URLEncoder`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

```
In[116]:= Needs["JLink`"]; InstallJava[];
  LoadJavaClass["java.net.URLEncoder"];

In[118]:= URLEncoder`encode["foo.cgi?abc=123"]
Out[118]= "foo.cgi%3Fabc%3D123"
```

There's also [`java.net.URLDecoder`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) for decoding.

Comment: Both answers are worthy of upvotes, but if it were my question I'd accept this one, because there's a lot of useful stuff you can  get via JLink that I always plain forget about.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my solution:

```
cat = StringJoin@@(ToString/@{##})&;         (* Like sprintf/strout in C/C++. *)
re = RegularExpression;

hex = IntegerString[#,16]&;        (* integer to hex, represented as a string *)
up = ToUpperCase;
asc = ToCharacterCode[#][[1]]&;                    (* character to ascii code *)
subst = StringReplace;

urlesc[s_String] := subst[s, {" "->"+", re@"[^\w\_\:\.]":>"%"<>up@hex@asc@"$0"}]
urlesc[x_] := urlesc@cat@x
unesc[s_String] := subst[s, re@"\\%(..)":>FromCharacterCode@FromDigits["$1",16]]
```

As a bonus, here's a function to encode a list of rules like `{a->2, b->3}` into GET parameters like `a=2&b=3`, with appropriate URL-encoding:

```
encode[c_] := cat @@ Riffle[cat[#1, "=", urlesc[#2]]& @@@ c, "&"]
```